# Possible for tooltips to show original vs transformed values in ggplotly with a transformed scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm a longtime ggplot2 user, but new to plotly. I'm currently working on a plot of ratios (eg, from a Cox proportional hazards model). I'd like to log-transform the scale, but when I do this and then use ggplotly(), the tooltips show the transformed values rather than the original value (eg, for an odds ratio of 1, it would show 0).

Is there a way to ask ggplotly() to show the original values instead? The `originalData` argument doesn't seem to be what I want, and I'm not finding any other leads.

Example:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 ref.level = 1,
                 or = seq(from = 1, by = 0.25, length.out = 10),
                 lcl = c(1, seq(from = 1.1, by = 0.1, length.out = 9)),
                 ucl = c(1, seq(from = 1.35, by = 0.35, length.out = 9)))

ggobj <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = or)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl))

ggobj %>% ggplotly()

## Plot ratios on log scale
ggobj <- ggobj +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log')

## Plot with ggplotly(); y, ymin, ymax tooltips are on transformed scale
ggobj %>% ggplotly()
```